# Single scalar from vector

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I am aware that this question is very general, but I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978747/represent-a-vector-with-a-scalar-value) and it made me curious. What are the sensible ways that you can think of to derive a single scalar value from a vector? Of course this procedure will vary a lot according to your data and your purpose and will result in an information loss, but what are the alternatives? For now, this is what I have (from linked question and mine):

- **Length**. Compute the Euclidean norm for each vector.
- **Max**. Take the maximum value of the vector.
- **Central tendency**. Mean, median, mode etc.
- **Measures of distribution shape**. Skewness and Kurtosis.
- **Dispersion**. Variance, standard deviation, IQR, range, entropy, etc.
- **Dimensionality reduction**. Perform some kind of dimensionality reduction (e.g. PCA, t-SNE, Isomap, etc.) to the vector set and keep the value of the first component.
- **Distance from centroid**. For every vector, compute the distance from the centroid and use this scalar as an index of the "eccentricity" of the vector.

Comment: That would completely depend on what is the goal. One can think of various ideas as well: count of non-zero values, sum of the values, hashing function, different kinds of norm... Everything is possible, but whether it's useful is a different question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also mentioned that in the question, but I was curious about all the possible methods to summarize a distribution with a single number, things that *can* be useful in the appropriate contexts